# in Angularjs {{$index}} loop only once insted of loop everytime

Tags: angularjs

in Angularjs **{{$index}}** loop only once insted of loop everytime

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in reports" class="all_report_admin">
            <div class="name">{{key}}</div>
            <div ng-repeat="data in value" class="all_report">
                <div class="date">{{$index+1}}</div>
                <div class="status">{{data.status}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How to restrict that 
[image]

Comment: Move it outside of the inner `ng-repeat`. If it will belong to `reports` loop, it will display the index once per `value` array. Or if you phrased it incorrectly and you still want it to be within the inner loop, but with the index of the parent's loop, then you need `{{$parent.$index + 1}}`

Comment: Actuall i want to show how many status is there so that i m using there

Answer (score 0):

try    `ng-repeat="data in value[0]"`  instead of your `ng-repeat`

Comment: Actually i don't want to loop index only rest is fine only restrict loop index only

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy combination that will give you such index (also known as a **counter**). It might look similar to how a one-dimensional array can be indexed with two-dimensional rows and columns, with `[column + row * columns]` formula (potentially `{{$index + $parent.$index * reports[key].length}}`). However, your `reports` can have an arbitrary number of object properties and arrays. So you need a manual counter in your controller.

I came up with this simple thing:

```
$scope.array = [];
var counter = 0;
for(key in $scope.reports){  // for every object
  var temp = [];             // row array
  for(var j=0; j<$scope.reports[key].length; j++){
    counter++;
    temp.push(counter);      // column element (counter)
  }
  $scope.array.push(temp);
}
```

Then it's enough to display it with `{{array[$parent.$index][$index]}}` in your inner `ng-repeat`

Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.reports = {
    "My reports 1":[
        {"status":"status1"},
        {"status":"status2"},
        {"status":"status3"}
      ],
    "My reports 2":[
        {"status":"status1"},
        {"status":"status2"},
        {"status":"status3"},
        {"status":"status4"},
      ],
    "My reports 3":[
        {"status":"status1"},
        {"status":"status2"},
      ],
    "My reports 4":[
        {"status":"status1"},
        {"status":"status2"},
        {"status":"status3"},
      ]
  };

  $scope.array = [];
  var counter = 0;
  for (key in $scope.reports) { // for every object
    var temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.reports[key].length; j++) {
      counter++;
      temp.push(counter);
    }
    $scope.array.push(temp);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in reports">
    <div>{{key}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="data in value">
      <strong>INDEX: {{array[$parent.$index][$index]}}</strong>
      <div>{{data.status}}</div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Mytesting it's better to post your `reports` array directly

Comment: "my2":[  
          {  
             "id":5,
             "cuid":20,
             "name":"my2",
             "month":"04",
             "created_at":"2018-04-01 00:00:00",
             "updated_at":"2018-04-11 00:00:00",
             "time":"04:32 PM",
             "status":"D"
          },
          {  
             "id":4,
             "cuid":20,
             "name":"my2",
             "month":"04",
             "created_at":"2018-04-02 00:00:00",
             "updated_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
             "time":"12:10 PM",
             "status":"P"
          },]

Comment: @Mytesting I don't understand what issue you have. Does my proposed solution work or not?

Comment: I just show each person record so that i want to index only one time but i used ur code that also same